# How to troubleshoot authorisation & authentication with Azure EventHub?

Tags: azure, apache-kafka, azure-eventhub

We have below credentials available:

```
EVENT_HUB="https://mynamespace.servicebus.windows.net"
CLIENT_ID=<Client_Id>
CLIENT_SECRET=<Client_Secret>
AZURE_TENANT_ID=<Tenant_Id>
```

---

How to troubleshoot authorization & authentication with EventHub?

Comment: Is the app identified by the client ID listed in the Access control tab of the Event Hub resource under one of the required Azure RBAC roles?

Comment: @juunas Access control tab? No idea, what this is... Can you provide more info? We are just users of EventHub

Comment: @juunas Can't we verify with a POST request?

Comment: No. You won't get enough info. The access should be verified through Azure Portal.

Comment: @juunas Am into azure portal EventHubs-> IAM -> CheckAccess... What next?

Comment: You can enter the app name there to check its accesses.

Comment: @juunas When you say, app name, you mean client_id?

Comment: No, the name that was assigned to the app when it was registered. I'm not sure if you can search by client ID there.

Comment: @juunas We have apps running in kubernetes Pods. Every Pod has its own service. Are you talking about service name?

Comment: Can you update your post with what type of the errors you are observing? Depending on where the error originated, the solution may be different.

Comment: I will try the following things:
1. Make sure if are using event hub's(topic in kafka) sas policy and not namespace sas policy.
2. Moreover if you have a jumpbox host(same VPC) , query event hub.
You also leverage [kafkacat] (https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/app-development/kafkacat-usage.html)

Comment: Example:
`kafkacat \
-b <your-hub-name>.servicebus.windows.net:9093\
-X security.protocol=sasl_ssl \
-X sasl.mechanism=PLAIN \
-X sasl.username='$ConnectionString' \
-X sasl.password='Endpoint=sb://<your-hub-name>.servicebus.windows.net/;SharedAccessKeyName=RootManageSharedAccessKey;SharedAccessKey=<primary-key>' \
-L`

Additional reference: https://dev.to/kenakamu/authenticating-event-hubs-publishers-with-sas-token-59i5